# When I load the map React leaflet will some open popups be initialized?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I was able to get the map reference using
const map = useRef (null) but now I need to have some popup open when I start the map;

```
const map = useRef (null);

<MapContainer
    zoom={15}
    center={state.currentLocation}
    
    whenCreated={(mapInstance) => {
      map.current = mapInstance;
    }}
  >{listFarol.map((place) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Marker
        key={place.id}
        position={place.pos}
        icon={myIcon}
   
      >
        {place.name=== 'A' ? (
          <Popup >{place.name}</Popup >
        ) : <Popup >{place.name}</Popup >} 

      </Marker>
    </>
  );
})}
<LocationMarker position={installActive} /></MapContainer>
```

But in case you want to use this reference to be able to define a series of popups that I want when the app starts open, in my case those that meet the condition place.name === 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a custom Marker comp which will have the popup open

```
function MarkerWithOpenPopup(props) {
  const markerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!markerRef.current) return;
    markerRef.current.openPopup();
  }, []);

  return <Marker ref={markerRef} {...props} />;
}
```

Then create a ternary for instance to decide which marker comp will be used during the loop:

```
{markers.map(({ name, id, pos }) => {
    const MarkerComp = name === "name 1" ? MarkerWithOpenPopup : Marker;
    return (
       <MarkerComp position={pos} icon={icon} key={id}>
         <Popup>{name}</Popup>
       </MarkerComp>
    );
})}
```

You can even improve this by providing a flag on the markers array and not checking the popup name explicitly

Here is a simplified [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3x-initialize-some-marker-popups-as-open-5kl2z)